# Printing in Silverlight/Lightswitch using XAML and custom controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, printing, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am programming a Silverlight application using Lightswitch. I want to print the data which is displayed on some screens.

I found [this tutorial](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3/Printing-With-LightSwitch.aspx) for printing in Silverlight/Lightswitch. It describes how to create a custom control using XAML which can be printed. The control looks like this:

[image: Printing in Lightswitch]

In the background you can see the control how it looks like in the Silverlight application. The control contrains both a button and a grid:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Print" Name="btnPrint" Click="btnPrint_Click" />
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <!-- grid code goes here -->
            <!-- some more code an closing tags -->
```

Using Silverlight's printing API, printing is done like this in the custom control:

```
PrintDocument printInvoice = new PrintDocument();
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e){   
    printInvoice.PrintPage +=
        new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(printInvoice_PrintPage);
}

void printInvoice_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
    e.PageVisual = LayoutRoot;
}
```

Since `e.PageVisual = LayoutRoot` is used, we only see the table in the printed output, and not the button. That's okay, but I would like to use a seperate XAML for the print layout. My goal is to just show a button `Print` on the Silverlight application, and define the print layout in a seperate XAML.

So, I just started to create a second XAML as SilverlightControl and tried to use it:

```
MyPrintLayout mpl = new MyPrintLayout();
void printArtikels_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
    e.PageVisual = mpl.LayoutRoot;
}
```

But I get the error "Das Element ist bereits das untergeordnete Element eines anderen Elements" (english: "The element is already the sub-element of another element"). This error was discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578109/wpf-datagrid-bug-when-toggle-visibility-on-a-column-with-an-image-as-headercont) as well, but it does not solve my problem.

When I include `MyPrintLayout` in the silverlight application it is displayed without a problem (there is only some text in it to test the functionality).

It seems like I am doing this completely wrong. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: @memorizer I saw you have answered my question, why is this post deleted now? It solved my problem, just wanted to accept it...

Comment: Sorry, wrong link pressed... =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mpl.LayoutRoot already sub-element of mpl. 
Try this:

```
void printArtikels_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){
    MyPrintLayout mpl = new MyPrintLayout();
    e.PageVisual = mpl;
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you! Now it is working as expected :)